# WCF certificate-based authentication result retreival

Tags: wcf

**Update**

I have a WCF service which uses certificate-based authentication, ie, no user name and password are required. On each request for a method, I want to check if the authentication is success or not. If it is not success, I can inform that user and return without doing anything. Is there a filter that will tell me that.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the failure to authenticate to be reflected in the return value from your operation, rather than a fault?

Assuming I understand you correctly (please correct if not), I question whether that's a good idea. In the case of failed authentication, you would be allowing a caller whose identity is completely unknown to execute application code. IMO a person shouldn't be permitted to run application code until after successful authentication.

Comment: If it is not success, I can inform that user and return without doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a CustomCerticateValidator. See the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx) for more information.